# unit testing with mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have to unit test a function (`SendMessageNetSkyToAgenceGrp`), and inside this function there is a service that I want to mock (`EnvoyerNotificationSms.SendMessageNetSky(signalRMessage)`):
Here is the code i want to test :

```
public void SendMessageNetSkyToAgenceGrp(
            int agenceId,
            string message,
            string name,
            bool addAgenceLibInMsg = true,
            SignalRMessageThemeEnum theme = SignalRMessageThemeEnum.Information)
        {
            Agence agence = AgenceCoreService.GetAgenceById(agenceId);

            if (agence == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(agence.Libelle) && addAgenceLibInMsg))
            {
                return;
            }

            string finalMessage = (message + (addAgenceLibInMsg ? agence.Libelle : ""));

            string groupName = string.Empty;

            if (theme == SignalRMessageThemeEnum.NotificationSms)
            {
                groupName = SignalRConstantes.GRP_SMSAGENCE + SignalRConstantes.SEPARATOR + agenceId;
            } 
            else
            {
                groupName = (SignalRConstantes.GRP_AGENCE + SignalRConstantes.SEPARATOR + agenceId);
            }

            SignalRMessage signalRMessage = new SignalRMessage(name, "", finalMessage, groupName, theme);

            EnvoyerNotificationSms.SendMessageNetSky(signalRMessage);
        }
```

And here is the test code:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Vérifier l'appel à l'infra IEnvoyerNotificationSms")]
        public void SendMessageNetSkyToAgenceGrp_CasNormal_ResultatOk()
        {
            // Arange            
            var envoyerNotificationSmMock = new Mock<IEnvoyerNotificationSms>();
            envoyerNotificationSmMock.Setup(envoyerNotifSms => envoyerNotifSms.SendMessageNetSky(It.IsAny<SignalRMessage>())).Verifiable();

            var SignalRCoreService = LocalIocManager.Resolve<ISignalRCoreService>();
            // Act 
            LocalIocManager.IocContainer.UseInstance(envoyerNotificationSmMock.Object, IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace);            
            SignalRCoreService.SendMessageNetSkyToAgenceGrp(56, "testMessage", "name", true, SignalRMessageThemeEnum.NotificationSms);

            // Assert
            envoyerNotificationSmMock.Verify(envoyerNotifSms => envoyerNotifSms.SendMessageNetSky(It.IsAny<SignalRMessage>()), Times.Once());
        }
```

But when I execute the test I get an error telling me that the service I want to mock is null (`EnvoyerNotificationSms.SendMessageNetSky(signalRMessage);`)
The error is : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in the line `EnvoyerNotificationSms.SendMessageNetSky(signalRMessage);`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the whole message error.

Comment: How does testable code look like?

Comment: In a unit test why don't you just instantiate the concrete `ISignalRCoreService` implementation you want to test? I see no reason for using an IoC manager here.

Comment: i update the question and i have put more code

Comment: you can't mock static methods. you need to pass EnvoyerNotificationSms as parameters to SendMessageNetSkyToAgenceGrp and mock that in the unit test

Comment: @Bizhan: SendMessageNetSky is not static method, the service EnvoyerNotificationSms is Injected inside SignalRCoreService;

Comment: it's hard to tell what's going wrong with the given code. please debug the constructor of SignalRCoreService and see what type of EnvoyerNotificationSms is it receiving. You may want to pass the mock object into the constructor.

Comment: Actually EnvoyerNotificationSms  is injected with property injection and not in the constructor

Comment: If it's injected via `Property Injection` can't you inject it *explicitly* on your `System under Test` (the object you're testing)? Instead of `LocalIocManager.IocContainer.UseInstance(envoyerNotificationSmMock.Object, IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace);`. I.e.: using the `setter`.

Comment: @Aage thanks the solution is in thiscontext, i see now what's the problem, it is the order of   ``` var SignalRCoreService = LocalIocManager.Resolve<ISignalRCoreService>();
            // Act 
            LocalIocManager.IocContainer.UseInstance(envoyerNotificationSmMock.Object, IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace); ```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the problem was the order of these lines :

```
var SignalRCoreService = LocalIocManager.Resolve<ISignalRCoreService>();
            // Act 
LocalIocManager.IocContainer.UseInstance(envoyerNotificationSmMock.Object, IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace);
```

In the second line has no effect, because the service i want to mock is already created in the first line. So the solution was to change the order of the two lines.